# v-for render items with groups by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

how render items with groups by date in Vue.js?

eg: I have an array of dynamic data like which will come from api with following type :

```
items: [
    {
        name: 'a',
        created: '2019-02-03T02:31:46.3485544'
    },
    {
        name: 'b',
        created: '2019-02-03T02:31:46.3485544'
    },
    {
        name: 'c',
        created: '2019-02-03T02:31:46.3485544'
    },
    {
        name: 'd',
        created: '2019-02-04T02:31:46.3485544'
    },
    {
        name: 'd',
        created: '2019-02-04T02:31:46.3485544'
    }
]
```

and i want to render list like that:

```
<p> items created today </p>
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>

<p> items created yesterday </p>
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>

<p> items created February 2 </p>
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>

<p> items created February 4 </p>
<ul>
    <li v-for="item in items">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

It's possible to do? I will receive this data always from api so it will be dynamic data, It's mean i will need to titles too get dynamically, i mean eg: items created February 4... items created February 3.. items created today etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a computed property to group your data by day:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          name: 'a',
          created: '2019-02-03T02:31:46.3485544'
        },
        {
          name: 'b',
          created: '2019-02-03T02:31:46.3485544'
        },
        {
          name: 'c',
          created: '2019-02-03T02:31:46.3485544'
        },
        {
          name: 'd',
          created: '2019-02-04T02:31:46.3485544'
        },
        {
          name: 'd',
          created: '2019-02-04T02:31:46.3485544'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    groupByDay() {
      let g = {};
      this.items.forEach(item => {
        let d = item.created.substring(0, 10);
        if (g[d]) {
          g[d].push(item.name);
        } else {
          g[d] = [];
          g[d].push(item.name);
        }
      });

      return g;

    }
  }

});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
   <div v-for="(item,key,index) in  groupByDay">
     <h5>items created : {{key}}</h5>
     <ul>
     <li v-for="name in item">{{name}}</li>
     </ul>
   
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to obtain array of arrays so you will iterate over the items.

It would be awesome if API could return the data grouped for you, so you can just iterate over it.

If you don't have that luxury, you need to group the data yourself. I'd recommend using https://date-fns.org/ for determining which group the item should go to.

Comment: If from api can't return me with groupped data?